# autoCompleteTextView set first item unclickable

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I created some searching algorithms for my app and it uses an `autoCompleteTextView`.

Right now, if a user will type some random letter which will give no result it will show a view saying no results were found, otherwise, it will show the results.

[image]

I would like to make the view of "no results were found" unclickable.
How can I make this work only for this case?

Can I do it without creating a custom Adapter?

Right now I use:

```
listAutoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>( getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_auto_search, autoNames );
atv_Search.setThreshold( 1 );
atv_Search.setAdapter( listAutoAdapter );
if (!autoBookNames.isEmpty() && notSelected) {
    atv_Search.showDropDown();
}

if (autoNames.isEmpty()){
    List<String> empty = new ArrayList<String>();
    empty.add("No results have been found");
    listAutoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>( getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_auto_search, empty );
    atv_Search.setThreshold( 1 );
    atv_Search.setAdapter( listAutoAdapter );
    atv_Search.showDropDown();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need a Custom AutoComplete Adapter.

Comment: I am from flutter, but i have have seen autoCompletionHint in android, You can set the hint to 'No results'  if there are no results